# Creating staggered layout

Tags: html, css

How I want it: [image: goal]

The code attached is the first subsection, working perfectly. I'm struggling to get it flip it like how I'd like in my attached photo (goal).

pls help

```css
.subsection-left {
    display: flex;
}
.subsection-content-left {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.start-format-left img {
  padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
}

.start-format-left h3 {
  padding: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.start-format-left p {
    max-width: 600px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="start-format-left">
      <div class="subsection-left">
        <!-- bring the image out of the subsection-content so it can displayed independent of the right column -->
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1067333/pexels-photo-1067333.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
        <div class="subsection-content-left">
          <h3>BLA BLA BLA</h3>
          <p>bla bla bla</p>
          <p>bla bla bla</p>
          <p>bla bla bla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for the right-side box, you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` on every x childs:

```css
.subsection-left {
    display: flex;
    Flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%
}

.subsection-left:nth-child(even) {
    display: flex;
    Flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

something in those lines?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am very new to web dev. Could you please implement it into my code?  Thanks :)

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/blissful-wildflower-2n87j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

this should work

Comment: The reason it might not have worked for you, is because you only need to copy the subsection divs, not the parent div when adding a new one) in that sandbox code I changed the names a bit to avoid confusion